# Как сделать, чтобы каждый jtextfield был привязан к своему jlabel?

Tags: applet, java, swing

Доброго времени суток! Кто подскажет, как сделать, чтобы каждый jtextfield был привязан к своему jlabel и они вместе были в одну линию, а следующая такая связка со следующей строки?

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("ФИО");
frame.setSize(500, 400);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

JPanel p = new JPanel();
frame.add(p);

p.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

JLabel labelName = new JLabel("Имя:");
labelName.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
JTextField firstName = new JTextField(20);
labelName.setLabelFor(firstName);

JLabel labelLastName = new JLabel("Фамилия:");
labelLastName.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
JTextField lastName = new JTextField(20);
labelLastName.setLabelFor(lastName);

p.add(labelName);
p.add(firstName);
p.add(labelLastName);
p.add(lastName);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Группируйте менеджерами разметки

**UPD:**
[A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)